# Edit lines below certain

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, vbscript

I need to edit the line below a certain line with a certain text
I am editing a .txt file using .bat or .vbs in windows 8.

Example

```
Account 1
ABC  -         Debit    900
     -         Credit   900
DEF  -         Debit    800
     -         Credit   100
```

I want the output to be like this

```
Account 1
ABC  -         Debit    900
ABC  -         Credit   900
DEF  -         Debit    800
DEF  -         Credit   100
```

Comment: I find that this regex helps(see the find portion here) https://i.imgur.com/sEihzzi.png  find `([A-Za-z]*)(\s+-[^\r\n]*\r\n)([\s]*)-`  replace with `$1$2$1-`  a command like perl or ack could perhaps be used.. eg a tool that can read new lines and apply a regular expression to a text file.

Comment: If possible I would like to do it in a batch file

Comment: The problem with generalized examples is they don't always match the real world. Is there always a hyphen on 6th position? You could store the last leading value and insert if none present.

Comment: @LotPings And the problem with a non-generalised example is it's way more complex than is necessary and this isn't a do your homework site so he is right to ask what he asked. No doubt if you can answer him on how to do it then that would answer his question, which is meant to be the goal. And questions are often useful to others too, which is another reason why not too specific is preferable if possible.

Comment: @AjSantos you need a command line program that foes find and replace with regexes.. and not sed 'cos sed won't see new lines..

Answer (score 0):

Editing in batch means rewriting the file, so this might work:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\04\17\SU_1314377.cmd
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "File=Accounts.txt"
Set "NewFile=Accounts2.txt"

(For /f "delims=" %%A in (%File%) do (
    Set "Line=%%A"
    Set "Debit=!Line:*Debit=!"
    Set "Credit=!Line:*Credit=!"
    If "!Line!" Neq "!Debit!"  Call Set "Account=%%Line:Debit!Debit!=%%"
    If "!Line!" Neq "!Credit!" Call Set "Line=!Account!Credit!Credit!"
    Echo:!Line!
) )> "%NewFile%"
```

- The batch extracts Debit/Credit values (with leading spaces) by replacing everything in the current line up to the words Debit/Credit.
- If the current line contains Debit the name in front is stored to var Account
- If the current line contains Credit the line is rebuilt with the stored value in front